# Make different click triggers to the same button

Tags: wordpress

here's my problem:

I'm using Sydney theme for WordPress and in the top, there's a built in call to action button, just a simple `<a></a>` and I'm using the plugin `Sumo` to create popup forms that open when clicking that button.

The trigger happens by giving `data-sumome-listbuilder-id=<id_number>"`, which is the id of a specific form.

So far so good, but I have 4 different languages and that means 4 different forms with 4 different id's.

At first I just edited the theme php file with the button and added the `data-sumome-listbuilder-id` to it (the costumize option in WordPress admin only lets me change the text and url of the button) but since now I need to add 3 more, I'm not sure how to make this work.

I'm also using the `Polylang` plugin to manage all languages, but besides different Url's and text, I don't see any option to give it attributes either.

Is there any workarround/plugin/built in option that let's me do this in a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple PHP switch did the trick:

```
if ($slider_button) {
    $currentLang = pll_current_language();

    switch ($currentLang) {
        case 'en':
            $id = 'id-form-1';
            break;
        case 'pt':
            $id = 'id-form-2';
            break;
        case 'pt_br':
            $id = 'id-form-3';
            break;
        case 'es':
            $id = 'id-form-4';
            break;
    }

    return '<a data-sumome-listbuilder-id="' . $id . '" href="' . esc_url($slider_button_url) . '" class="roll-button button-slider">' . esc_html($slider_button) . '</a>';
}
```